# slapd configuration for back-sql: how to traslate examples from slapd.conf to slapd.d

Tags: ldap, postgresql, sql, slapd

I'm trying to configure slapd with back-sql (specifically postgresql backend). All documents I found ([Postgresq LDAP Howto](http://www.darold.net/projects/ldap_pg/HOWTO/x12.html%20this) seems to be more complete) are related to old configuration that use slapd.conf while I need to use the news slapd.d dynamic one.

I can't understand how I should add the entry in the confguration. What I currenty tried is:

```
dn: olcDatabase={1}sql,cn=config
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
objectClass: olcSqlConfig
olcSuffix: dc=vega,dc=com
olcDatabase: sql
olcDbName: mytest
```

But when I run ldapmodify I get the error:

```
root@argo-jessie:~# ldapmodify -x  -D cn=admin,cn=config -W  -f ,ldapvi-argo-jessie-7228.ldif
Enter LDAP Password: 
adding new entry "olcDatabase={1}sql,cn=config"
ldap_add: Other (e.g., implementation specific) error (80)
    additional info: <olcSuffix> failed startup
```

And at 254 debugLevel I get:

```
Sep 23 16:34:18 localhost slapd[5650]: olcSuffix: value #0: <olcSuffix> failed startup (dc=vega,dc=com)!
Sep 23 16:34:18 localhost slapd[5650]: send_ldap_result: err=80 matched="" text="<olcSuffix> failed startup"
```

In making the test on Debian Jessie with slapd versione 2.4.40

Answer (score 0):

I have been totally disouraged by a couple of guys [from the slapd list](http://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-technical/201509/msg00141.html) from using this backend as it is considered experimental and not supported.